# TeXworks PDF viewer zoom

Tags: texworks

In TexWorks pdf viewer is there anyway to zoom to a numerically specified size. Their is no options under "view" that seems to do this. In the bottom left hand corner you can click on the percentage and get "150%" "75%" etc. but I don't see any box where you can input a fixed percentage.

Sorry in advance if this has been asked before, I only see other issues with the viewer in a stackexchange search (there are a lot of them).

Comment: `File`-->`Edit`-->`Preferences`-->`Preview`--> select `Default scaling`= `500 or whatever`and Press `Ok`. TeXworks might require a Restart to take settings into effect. But I recommend `Fit to Width` and `Fit to Window` which are more accessible,suitable and adaptable settings for PDF viewer in TeXworks shown at the same place where you find "150%" "75%" etc..

Comment: Well actually the reason why I wanted a specified percentage is because I wanted to see all the page minus borders (not the full page), but your preferences option works for this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TeXworks:

`File`-->`Edit`-->`Preferences`-->`Preview`--> select `Default scaling`= `500 or whatever`and `Press Ok`. TeXworks might require a Restart to take settings into effect.

One can also use `Fit to Width` and `Fit to Window` which are more adaptable settings for PDF viewer in TeXworks shown right hand side bottom of PDF viewer window where you find "150%" "75%" etc.